SharePoint List form customized powerapps form display error connection not configured for this data source
I have a SharePoint list form customized powerapps form.It was wioking fine for all the users. Recently one of the user reporting that the error he is getting while opening the power apps form is 'connection not configured for this data source'. While opening the form oeach time it fisrt popups up the App Prmission allow popup and then above error.
I tried readding the lists to the data connections and published. but the issue is still ther for this specific user.
Any help on this would realy help me .
Thanks in advance.

This error can occur when a user does not have the appropriate permissions to access the data source, or when the data source has not been properly configured.
According to your description, I 'd suggest you check the user's permissions for the SharePoint list and ensure that he has the appropriate access to the data source.
If the issue persists, try clearing the user's cache and cookies, or have them try accessing the app from a different browser or device.

Hello Amy,
Thanks for your answer. I have already tried doing above suggested approaches. but no luck
